# How to upload a file( image, PDF or video etc ) with faker in Laravel testing

Tags: laravel, file, testing, faker

I am writing tests for laravel. I need to pass these validation rules.
Please guide how can I upload fake image and video in my test. thanks

Here is what i tried.

```
`'image' => ['required', 'file', 'mimes:jpg,jpeg,bmp,png'],
'video' => ['required', 'file', 'mimes:mp4'],
```

Comment: I am not in my computer right now, but read the documentation, it explains exactly how to do that: https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/mocking#storage-fake

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You just provided the validation rules you need to get passed. However in order to upload a file with faker in laravel testing you can use `use Illuminate\Http\UploadedFile;`

```
'image' => UploadedFile::fake()->image('file1.png', 600, 600),
'video' => UploadedFile::fake()->create('sample.mp4', '1000', 'mp4'),
'file' = UploadedFile::fake()->create($faker->word . '.pdf', 100);
```

This is how you can use Faker to generate a fake image, video or pdf file with a random name and specified size.